# Can SFINAE be used to select an overload of a template method within a template class?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm attempting to apply SFINAE in C++03 to a `std::vector` clone (for educational purposes) in order to restrict the type of iterator passed to the constructor:

```
struct input_iterator_tag {};
struct output_iterator_tag {};

struct InputIter {
    typedef input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};

struct OutputIter {
    typedef output_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};

template<class T>
class Vector {
public:
    explicit Vector(size_t, T=T());

    template <class InputIt>
    Vector(InputIt, InputIt, input_iterator_tag = typename InputIt::iterator_category());
};

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(size_t, T)
{
    std::cout << "size_t overload called" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
template <class InputIt>
Vector<T>::Vector(InputIt, InputIt, input_iterator_tag)
{
    std::cout << "input iterator overload called" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InputIter input;
    OutputIter output;

    Vector<int> a(0, 0);
    Vector<int> b(input, input);
    // Should fail to compile:
    Vector<int> c(output, output);
}
```

The compiler (g++-4.9) correctly rejects the definition of vector `c` (passed the wrong type of iterator), but also rejects the definition of vector `a`, failing with:

```
sfinae.cpp: In constructor 'Vector<T>::Vector(InputIt, InputIt, input_iterator_tag) [with InputIt = int; T = int]':
sfinae.cpp:42:23: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
     Vector<int> a(0, 0);
                       ^
sfinae.cpp:42:23: note:   when instantiating default argument for call to Vector<T>::Vector(InputIt, InputIt, input_iterator_tag) [with InputIt = int; T = int]
```

Why is the substitution failure classified as an error here?

Comment: could be a compiler bug - `clang` 3.3 compiles

Comment: @Praetorian - meh. This is "why is this bad attempt at SFINAE not working" rather than "why do I need SFINAE".

Comment: Anyway, SFINAE applies to the function signature and any default template arguments that are used. It doesn't apply to default function arguments.

Comment: @T.C. True, but his *SFINAE constructor* is being called because he doesn't constrain it. Both Barry's and my answers explain that part. If you want to expand on what else is wrong you can use your un-dupe hammer.

Comment: [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a66b8f2cefce6fc) an example of how you'd use SFINAE to ensure an input iterator is being passed to the constructor. Note how the error message differs from your version. Yours failed because `output_iterator_tag` iterator tag cannot be converted to `input_iterator_tag`. Mine fails because no function with a matching signature was found, meaning that that constructor was SFINAE'd out.

Comment: @Praetorian - Thanks. I'm trying to do this without C++11's `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_same` -- any ideas?

Comment: @claymation Each of these two takes something like 4 lines to implement.

Comment: @claymation `enable_if` + `is_same` is the only way that I know of doing this with a C++03 compiler. If you want [another C++11 way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9e68d09cc5c7e82) of doing it, you can use expression SFINAE to try to construct an `input_iterator_tag` from `InputIt::iterator_category`, that will succeed for any tag type derived from `input_iterator_tag`